# Unable to make cross domain AJAX request (localhost:50675 to localhost:27081) using IIS Express with 2 separate projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

In Visual Studio 2015 I have 2 projects in my solution: ASP.NET MVC app and an ASP.NET Web API app. The MVC app uses a different port in IIS express than the Web API app.

In the debugger I see that I end up in the ChangeName method Web API controller, but the parameter never gets set and then in the console I see errors. The errors have to do with cross domain problems.

Is it this complicated to make a jQuery AJAX request to a different domain? When I use fiddler everything works fine.

The domain for the app that the below code is in is: localhost:50675 and I am trying to make a request to another project in the same solution that is localhost:27081

**Here is my AJAX request:**

```
$("#btnChangeName").click(function() {
    var name = $("#Name").val();

    var url = 'http://localhost:27081/api/products/changename';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: JSON.stringify({name: name}),
        success: successFuncApi,
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

**Here is one of the errors I am seeing in the console:**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:27081/api/products/changename. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost:50675' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 500.

I am not sure if the error is due to my controller erroring since the param is null or if it is the root of my problem.

Comment: What browser do you user?  Do you see the same problem on all browsers?  I know IE is very finicky about this stuff.

Comment: I am using Chrome. Is this a normal problem or should it simply be working? In postman and fiddler the request and response work fine but I am not using jQuery AJAX in fiddler.

Comment: Umm... this might be your problem?   https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error occurs because you send a request from origin (source) to another one.

all you need to do is to enable cross origin in your backend (or your ASP.NET Web API) to be added in the header.

[this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) link will give you more information, and guide you to enable cross-origin requests.

Answer (score 1):

This error might go away, when you move your apps to production (depending on the setup of webservers). As for now, I would try something, as explained here [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). If this doesn't fit your situation, there are other ways to enable the same thing.

You could also deploy your apps on IIS. Create app for client, then add new app to that app for webapi.